# Is it possible to submit and display links in Google Shopping without bidding on keywords or adding product data?

Tags: google-shopping

I hear Google Product Search will be changing to "Google Shopping" and I want to know if users will be able to upload links to be displayed even if you don't have accommodating product "data" to accommodate and/or without partaking in an AdSense style pay per click model. I read a lot already but I am wondering if there is any information I missed before I throw in the towel and accept that the conclusion that it will be a completely paid service.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this blog post](http://googlecommerce.blogspot.com/2012/05/building-better-shopping-experience.html) on the Google Commerce blog sums it up:

> First, we are starting to transition Google Product Search in the U.S.
>   to a purely commercial model built on Product Listing Ads.

So in essence, you will have to pay for a listing on Google Shopping. At this stage it only applies to the US site, but barring mishap it will no doubt be rolled out everywhere eventually.

If you are not marketing to the US, you can still submit to Google's [Merchant Center](http://www.google.com/merchants) for free.

Answer (score -3):

it is possible to simply just the webshop to log into Google Shopping. It costs nothing. It is similar to Google search. Please note that your site must generate a feed that your products up to date.

Comment: Perhaps you need to adjust the grammar a bit (die eerste zin loopt niet echt....)